# Use of NMOS in an i2c bus

Tags: mosfet, i2c, nmos

I have been studying the following schematic.

[image]

Those NMOSes are depletion type. I am not sure why they are needed in this. Why not just connect SCL and SDA busses together without a MOSFET? What purpose do the mosfets serve here?

Comment: you may have been studying the schematic, but you have not been actually seeing the schematic .... have a really close look at the circuitry around the NMOS

Comment: Sorry sir, I am currently a junior engineer.

Comment: Why do you think the N-channel MOSFETs are depletion-mode? They are almost certainly enhancement-mode, which would be correct for this kind of level translation.

Comment: @DaveTweed, perfect question. Notice, on the MOSFET symbol, how the line at the end of the arrow is straight, not dashed. AFAIK, that corresponds to depletion type MOSFET. Here's an image that compares the types. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N2Fz.png

Comment: You're reading too much into the symbol. Few people follow that convention any more. To be sure, read the datasheet for the actual device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mosfet is converting a 3.3V signal from the MS5611 to a 5V signal.  When SDA is low (0v), the N_MOS will be on, pulling H_SDA low.  When SDA is high (3.3v) the N_MOS will be off (Vgs = 0), allowing the H_SDA line to be pulled high (5V) by R14.

Comment: Don't the depletion mode mosfets still conduct between drain and source even if the gate-source voltage is 0?

Comment: It will conduct only from source to drain due to the inherent body diode. So the diode is blocking any current flow from the +5V side to the +3.3V side.

Answer (score 0):

This N-MOS circuit is the very basic form of level translation, between 5-V signal domain, to 3.3-V signal domain. For more insights see this [EETimes article](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1231111).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those MOSFETS are level translators / isolators.
They translate between 3.3V and 5V levels.
If you just connected the I2C signals together the levels would be wrong and/or could damage parts that are not 5V tolerant.

Comment: Then, if I use a 3.3V logic MCU, I would not need a level translation, correct?

Comment: If all devices on the I2C bus are running from +3.3V power then translation is not needed.